User cannot delete emails from deleted items folder
I am working with a user who has been using their Deleted Items folder as long-term storage. It says that there are about 29,000 emails in the folder, but I suspect there are many more.
They have emails dating back to 2006 that are still in there, they have purposefully turned off autoarchive.
Now they cannot delete emails without them coming back into their Deleted Items box.
After running some scripts to get some more information, it shows that their recoverable items folder is at 100 GB.
There are no litigation holds, and no other rules that would keep emails in there.
Any ideas?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

@John, I wish I could. Trust me.

@DrMoishePippik Anything amount that we try to delete returns to their deleted items folder. Thank you for the input!

It seems like the user is experiencing a common issue where deleted emails keep reappearing in the deleted items folder. This can happen due to various reasons, such as synchronization issues or settings in the email client. Here are a few suggestions that might help:

Check the Email Client Settings: In some email clients like Outlook, there's an option called "Mark items for deletion" which, if enabled, might cause deleted emails to reappear. Make sure this option is unchecked.

Reset Folders: In Outlook, you can try resetting the folders using the command outlook /resetfolders.

Rebuild the OST file: If the user is using Outlook on a desktop or mobile app, there might be a problem with the OST file, which stores a copy of the emails on the device. Deleting and rebuilding the OST file.


Regarding the Recoverable Items folder, the folder has its own storage quota, which is separate from the mailbox quota. The storage quota for the Recoverable Items folder is automatically increased from 30 GB to 100 GB when a hold is placed on a mailbox in Exchange Online. If the archive mailbox is enabled, the storage quota for the Recoverable Items folder in the archive mailbox is also increased from 30 GB to 100 GB.

Try to follow the instructions in the article Delete items in the Recoverable Items folder of cloud-based mailboxes on hold at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/purview/ediscovery-delete-items-in-the-recoverable-items-folder-of-mailboxes-on-hold?view=o365-worldwide

As is, this is a comment -- it does not give the specific directions; it just refers to a link which might disappear. Abstract them from the reference and put them in an answer.
